# How to get AirPlay from UIWebView to continue playback when app is backgrounded *without* setting AVAudioSession category to Playback?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I've been attempting to make this work for quite a while now:

My app has the potential to play videos of Youtube from within UIWebView. The user could want to use AirPlay for this. When AirPlay is on, the device could go to sleep and normally video stops playing moments after that happens. As advised in other posts, I set the `AVAudioSession` category to the `Playback` one and it works - AirPlay continues even when the device display goes to sleep.

However, this has a side-effect; if the user has activated the app while music playback is on in the background, setting the app's audio session category to Playback causes the playing music to stop and this is definitely annoying.

Ideally, I want to set the AVAudioSession category when playback of Video starts, not when my App is activated - but I've not seen any central or UIWebview notification / delegate method to determine this.

I've got a *hackish* workaround for iPhone where the UIWebview hosted video player always loads full screen modal and thus can be determined. But my app is Universal and on iPad the video starts inline; I can't figure out a way to know when Video playback is going to happen. This is exactly the point when the audio category should be switched to Playback - it will actually help users who want background music playing only until video starts up.

I don't want to fool around with adding Javascript events on to Video tags inside the UIWebView - that seems too fragile to me.

Is it possible to observe any AVFoundation notifications that trigger for the UIWebView video playback? Or anyone know of any other way to determine if video playback will start / has started?